# Help installing resilio-sync

Tags: dpkg, architecture, btsync

I have a 64-bit desktop PC running Ubuntu 16.04. I decided that I wanted to discontinue relying on cloud drives and start using a torrent sync among multiple local hard drives. This way, I won't have to pay an annual premium for a sizable capacity for my music and photos. Previously, this was bittorrent sync or btsync, but it seems to be now called resilio-sync. So, I followed the following instructions located here: https://help.getsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/206178924.

I followed the section for Ubuntu. I copied and pasted the selection box with the following commands,

```
echo "deb http://linux-packages.resilio.com/resilio-sync/deb resilio-sync non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/resilio-sync.list
wget -qO - https://linux-packages.resilio.com/resilio-sync/key.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
sudo apt-get update
```

I then did

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and added the following at the bottom of the file:

```
deb [arch=armhf] http://linux-packages.resilio.com/resilio-sync/deb resilio-sync non-free
```

NOTE: This is where my problem is.
Whenever I `sudo apt-get update` I get:

> Err:31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main armhf Packages
>     404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
>   Err:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main armhf Packages
>     404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
>   Err:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main armhf Packages
>     404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
>   Err:48 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main armhf Packages
>     404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
>   E: Failed to fetch   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-armhf/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
>   E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
>   E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
>   E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
>   E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

It seems I can indeed install resilio-sync with,

```
sudo apt-get install resilio-sync
```

However, I don't think the armhf architecture installed correctly because it reflects that in the apt-get update results. I tried verifying with `dpkg --print-architecture` and it returns amd64. I assume since the update fails, the armhf is unable to fully install.

Comment: Just a side note : Resilio sync is closed source software. Did you look at Syncthing (open source) ? https://syncthing.net/

Comment: Your pastebin was removed

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why my pastbin was removed. I'm still new to these conventions to posting stuff. I think I'll just pivot and try using Syncthing.

Answer (score 0):

Which CPU do you have? If it is either an Intel or AMD (which is most likely the case) the architecture you added (ARM) is wrong. Try the following:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then replacing `[arch=armhf]` with `deb` and save the file
Lastly, run the update and install again:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install resilio-sync
```